# Spring boot - set dynamic property on creation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an object which has an attribute in its constructor which is created dynamically dependant on another object it takes in.

```
    public Booking(Customer customer, Barber barber, LocalDateTime startTime, Service service) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.barber = barber;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.service = service;
    this.endTime = null;
    this.calculateEndTime();
}

    public void calculateEndTime(){
    int duration = this.service.getDuration();
    this.setEndTime(this.startTime.plusMinutes(duration));
}
```

When I seed data via a dataloader which implements ApplicationRunner my bookings are created with an endTime.  However when I post a new booking via insomnia this `calculateEndTime()` function doesn't run, my endTime stays as `null`.

As far as i understand it, this is due to spring looking at the default empty constructor and setters to create the new object.

So my question is, why does it work via the data loader and how can I get this to generate via posting a new booking via the front end/insomnia?

I have tried calling this function within the endTime setter but this does not work.

Example of seeded data via data loader:

```
@Component
public class DataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {

@Autowired
BarberRepository barberRepository;

@Autowired
CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@Autowired
BookingRepository bookingRepository;


@Autowired
ServiceRepository serviceRepository;


public DataLoader() {

}

public void run(ApplicationArguments args) {

Service beardTrim = new Service("Beard Trim", 5.00, 10);
serviceRepository.save(beardTrim);

Barber alan = new Barber("Alan");
barberRepository.save(alan);

Customer customer1 = new Customer("Joe");
customerRepository.save(customer1);

LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.NOVEMBER, 5, 12, 00);

Booking booking1 = new Booking(customer1, alan, startTime, beardTrim);
bookingRepository.save(booking1);

}
```

Example of data I'm trying to post via Insomnia:

```
{
"startTime": "2018-11-12T09:00",
"barber": "http://localhost:8080/api/barbers/1",
"service": "http://localhost:8080/api/services/1",
"customer": "http://localhost:8080/api/customers/1"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Put the code that seeds your data and POST calls too.

Comment: Please see above edit to show example data.

Comment: What's your Rest endpoint for that specific request?

Comment: Without seeing your REST endpoint, if I were to guess, you need a custom Json deserializer .

Comment: My REST endpoint is spring data rest.  

My endTime property is annotated like


    `@JsonSerialize(using=LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private LocalDateTime endTime;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this was to write a custom post route where `calculateEndTime()` can be called on the object before saving it.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution to this rather than writing a custom postrout is to use the @prePersist annotation.

My 70odd line custom post was cut down to an if statement used with @prePersist.